# i try to tet google analytics property data using php curl api

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics-api, access-token

**Please someone help me, I'm stuck in this problem since last 7 days...**

I want to do something like this. Suppose i have multiple users property id, Client ID and  Client secret
and i using this API :

$apiEndpoint = 'https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/'.env('ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID').':runReport';

Now I want to get Google Analytics data of particular user. And My Curl code this :

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $apiRequestEndpoint,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $requestData,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

return $response;
```

```
$requestData = [
                'dateRanges' => [
                    [
                       'startDate' => $request->startDate,
                        'endDate' => $request->endDate
                    ]
                ],
                'dimensions' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'sessionDefaultChannelGroup'
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'date'
                    ]
                ],
                'metrics' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'totalUsers'
                    ],
                ],
                'dimensionFilter' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'fieldName' => 'sessionDefaultChannelGroup',
                        'inListFilter' => [
                            'values' => ['Organic Search']
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'orderBys' => [
                    [
                        'dimension' => [
                            'orderType' => 'NUMERIC',
                            'dimensionName' => 'date'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'keepEmptyRows' => true,
                'metricAggregations' => [
                    'TOTAL'
                ]
            ];
```

Generate access token code here :

```
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Analytics;

$client = new Google_Client();
        
// Set OAuth2 credentials
$client->setClientId($request->client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($request->client_secret);

$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// Set the correct redirect URI
$client->setRedirectUri('http://127.0.0.1:8000/goback');

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    
    return redirect($authUrl);
}

// Exchange authorization code for an access token
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
$jsonData = $client->getAccessToken();    

// Get the access token
if (isset($jsonData['access_token'])) { 
    $accessToken = $jsonData['access_token'];
    return $accessToken;
} else {
    return 'Access token not found in the JSON data.'
    }
```

**Note : Whenever I get google analytics date from a client. I have to login my google account every time.**

**So, I wish I don't have to login to my Gmail Account  and get an access token for call a API. Can I do this and how ?**

And I'm doing this feature in backend side PHP Laravel framework

composer require google/apiclient

Comment: You are redirecting to the auth URL, every time the `code` parameter is not set. But the existence of that parameter is the _result_ of sending the user to the auth URL in the first place. You should call `getAccessToken` first, to see if the client can already provided you with an access token based on previous operations, and only send the user to the auth URL, if that was not the case.